# Spacing between boxes using bootstrap responsive scheme

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, spacing

I have a this layout based on bootstrap.

I've manually added a margin between the rows, but when I resize the page I want the columns to have vertical spacing between them as well.

How should I do this?

**Full-size browser:**

[image]

**Resized browser:**

[image]

**Ans here's the code:**

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row top-buffer">

    <!-- VISITORS -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="widget-body widget-white fixed-h-single-number-chart-sm">
        <span class="light-grey">VISITORS</span>  <span class="badge badge-question" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Number of unique visitors to your web site"><small>?</small></span>
        <br />
        <span class="single-number-md">4,700</span>
        <small>visitors</small>
        <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">10%&#x25B2;</span>
        <div class="chart" style="height:105px;" id="visitors-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/col-md-4-->

    <!-- TRIALS IN PROGRESS -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="widget-body widget-white fixed-h-single-number-chart-sm">
        <span class="light-grey">TRIALS IN PROGRESS</span>  <span class="badge badge-question" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Number of trials in progress"><small>?</small></span>
        <br />
        <span class="single-number-md" data-toggle="counterup">235</span>
        <small>trials</small>
        <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">7%&#x25B2;</span>
        <div class="chart" style="height:105px;" id="trials-in-progress-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/col-md-4-->

    <!-- NEW CUSTOMERS -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="widget-body widget-white fixed-h-single-number-chart-sm">
        <span class="light-grey">NEW CUSTOMERS</span>  <span class="badge badge-question" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Number of new customers acquired this month"><small>?</small></span>
        <br />
        <span class="single-number-md">56</span>
        <small>customers</small>
        <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">2%&#x25B2;</span>
        <div class="chart" style="height:105px;" id="new-customers-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/col-md-4-->

  </div>
  <!--/row-->

  <div class="row top-buffer">

    <!-- VISITORS TO TRIALS -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="widget-body widget-white fixed-h-single-number-chart-sm">
        <span class="light-grey">VISITORS TO TRIALS</span>  <span class="badge badge-question" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Percentage of visitors that have signed up for trial accounts"><small>?</small></span>
        <br
        />
        <span class="single-number-md" data-toggle="counterup">5%</span>
        <small>conversion</small>
        <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">7%&#x25B2;</span>
        <div class="chart" style="height:105px;" id="visitors-to-trials-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/col-md-4-->

    <!-- TRIALS TO PURCHASE -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="widget-body widget-white fixed-h-single-number-chart-sm">
        <span class="light-grey">TRIALS TO PURCHASE <span class="badge badge-question" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Percentage of trials converted to purchases"><small>?</small></span></span>
        <br />
        <span class="single-number-md">17%</span>
        <small>conversion</small>
        <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">9%&#x25B2;</span>
        <div class="chart" style="height:105px;" id="trials-to-purchase-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/col-md-4-->

    <!-- TOTAL CUSTOMERS -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="widget-body widget-white fixed-h-single-number-chart-sm">
        <span class="light-grey">TOTAL CUSTOMERS</span>  <span class="badge badge-question" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Number of total active customers"><small>?</small></span>
        <br />
        <span class="single-number-md">488</span>
        <small>customers</small>
        <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">2%&#x25B2;</span>
        <div class="chart" style="height:105px;" id="total-customer-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/col-md-4-->

  </div>
  <!--/row-->

  <div class="row top-buffer bottom-buffer">

    <!-- FTE SALES REPS -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="widget-body widget-white fixed-h-single-number-chart-sm">
        <span class="light-grey">FTE SALES REPRESENTATIVES </span>  <span class="badge badge-question" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Percentage of visitors that have signed up for trial accounts"><small>?</small></span>
        <br
        />
        <span class="single-number-md" data-toggle="counterup">6</span>
        <small>sales reps</small>
        <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">20%&#x25B2;</span>
        <div class="chart" style="height:105px;" id="fte-sales-reps-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/col-md-4-->

    <!-- QUOTA PER SALES REP -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="widget-body widget-white fixed-h-single-number-chart-sm">
        <span class="light-grey">QUOTA PER SALES REP <span class="badge badge-question" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Percentage of trials converted to purchases"><small>?</small></span></span>
        <br />
        <span class="single-number-md">$4,200</span>
        <small>dollars</small>
        <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">9%&#x25B2;</span>
        <div class="chart" style="height:105px;" id="quota-per-sales-rep-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/col-md-4-->

    <!-- FORECASTED SALES -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="widget-body widget-white fixed-h-single-number-chart-sm">
        <span class="light-grey">FORECASTED SALES </span>  <span class="badge badge-question" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Number of total active customers"><small>?</small></span>
        <br />
        <span class="single-number-md">$25,200</span>
        <small>dollars</small>
        <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">2%&#x25B2;</span>
        <div class="chart" style="height:105px;" id="forecasted-sales-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/col-md-4-->

  </div>
  <!--/row-->

</div>
<!--container-fluid-->
```

Thanks!!

Comment: When you resize, use Firebug to determine the name of the class that is being applied to those divs, or if it's using a media query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you simply add a `margin-bottom: 30px` on your widget class and remove it from the rows?

```css
.widget-body {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.widget-white {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container-fluid {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row top-buffer">

    <!-- VISITORS -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="widget-body widget-white fixed-h-single-number-chart-sm">
        <span class="light-grey">VISITORS</span>  <span class="badge badge-question" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Number of unique visitors to your web site"><small>?</small></span>
        <br />
        <span class="single-number-md">4,700</span>
        <small>visitors</small>
        <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">10%&#x25B2;</span>
        <div class="chart" style="height:105px;" id="visitors-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/col-md-4-->

    <!-- TRIALS IN PROGRESS -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="widget-body widget-white fixed-h-single-number-chart-sm">
        <span class="light-grey">TRIALS IN PROGRESS</span>  <span class="badge badge-question" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Number of trials in progress"><small>?</small></span>
        <br />
        <span class="single-number-md" data-toggle="counterup">235</span>
        <small>trials</small>
        <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">7%&#x25B2;</span>
        <div class="chart" style="height:105px;" id="trials-in-progress-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/col-md-4-->

    <!-- NEW CUSTOMERS -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="widget-body widget-white fixed-h-single-number-chart-sm">
        <span class="light-grey">NEW CUSTOMERS</span>  <span class="badge badge-question" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Number of new customers acquired this month"><small>?</small></span>
        <br />
        <span class="single-number-md">56</span>
        <small>customers</small>
        <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">2%&#x25B2;</span>
        <div class="chart" style="height:105px;" id="new-customers-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/col-md-4-->

  </div>
  <!--/row-->

  <div class="row top-buffer">

    <!-- VISITORS TO TRIALS -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="widget-body widget-white fixed-h-single-number-chart-sm">
        <span class="light-grey">VISITORS TO TRIALS</span>  <span class="badge badge-question" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Percentage of visitors that have signed up for trial accounts"><small>?</small></span>
        <br
        />
        <span class="single-number-md" data-toggle="counterup">5%</span>
        <small>conversion</small>
        <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">7%&#x25B2;</span>
        <div class="chart" style="height:105px;" id="visitors-to-trials-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/col-md-4-->

    <!-- TRIALS TO PURCHASE -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="widget-body widget-white fixed-h-single-number-chart-sm">
        <span class="light-grey">TRIALS TO PURCHASE <span class="badge badge-question" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Percentage of trials converted to purchases"><small>?</small></span></span>
        <br />
        <span class="single-number-md">17%</span>
        <small>conversion</small>
        <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">9%&#x25B2;</span>
        <div class="chart" style="height:105px;" id="trials-to-purchase-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/col-md-4-->

    <!-- TOTAL CUSTOMERS -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="widget-body widget-white fixed-h-single-number-chart-sm">
        <span class="light-grey">TOTAL CUSTOMERS</span>  <span class="badge badge-question" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Number of total active customers"><small>?</small></span>
        <br />
        <span class="single-number-md">488</span>
        <small>customers</small>
        <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">2%&#x25B2;</span>
        <div class="chart" style="height:105px;" id="total-customer-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/col-md-4-->

  </div>
  <!--/row-->

  <div class="row top-buffer bottom-buffer">

    <!-- FTE SALES REPS -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="widget-body widget-white fixed-h-single-number-chart-sm">
        <span class="light-grey">FTE SALES REPRESENTATIVES </span>  <span class="badge badge-question" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Percentage of visitors that have signed up for trial accounts"><small>?</small></span>
        <br
        />
        <span class="single-number-md" data-toggle="counterup">6</span>
        <small>sales reps</small>
        <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">20%&#x25B2;</span>
        <div class="chart" style="height:105px;" id="fte-sales-reps-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/col-md-4-->

    <!-- QUOTA PER SALES REP -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="widget-body widget-white fixed-h-single-number-chart-sm">
        <span class="light-grey">QUOTA PER SALES REP <span class="badge badge-question" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Percentage of trials converted to purchases"><small>?</small></span></span>
        <br />
        <span class="single-number-md">$4,200</span>
        <small>dollars</small>
        <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">9%&#x25B2;</span>
        <div class="chart" style="height:105px;" id="quota-per-sales-rep-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/col-md-4-->

    <!-- FORECASTED SALES -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="widget-body widget-white fixed-h-single-number-chart-sm">
        <span class="light-grey">FORECASTED SALES </span>  <span class="badge badge-question" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Number of total active customers"><small>?</small></span>
        <br />
        <span class="single-number-md">$25,200</span>
        <small>dollars</small>
        <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">2%&#x25B2;</span>
        <div class="chart" style="height:105px;" id="forecasted-sales-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/col-md-4-->

  </div>
  <!--/row-->

</div>
<!--container-fluid-->
```

Comment: This is perfect and definitely the easiest way to do it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try with a little media query like this:

```
@media (max-width:992px) {
    .top-buffer > div {
       margin-top:10px;
    }
}
```

Or if suits your styles you can target the widget class:

```
@media (max-width:992px) {
    .widget-body {
       margin-top:10px;
    }
}
```

Check this **[BootplyDemo](http://www.bootply.com/ocIMoIxqLA)**

Comment: Thanks for your help! It would definitely works too.